# How do I make my code (a car driving across the screen) repeat and start at the beginning again?

Tags: python, loops

```
counter = 0
while True:
    for counter in range(0, 50):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        helpers.update_position(canvas, 'car1', x=10, y=0)
        gui.update()
```

Comment: You question isn't specific enough. If you need help with python syntax please research first on Python syntax including loops. In addition specify more of your code and more of the outcome of the program as if you are a scientist researching.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing constant ***x*** and ***y*** values into your ***update_position()*** function. Assuming the ***x*** is the horizontal axis, you should be passing in ***x=counter*** as the third argument to the function ***update_position()***. Also, you do not need to declare the ***counter*** variable separately as you have done on line #1 of your code snippet.

```
while True:
   for counter in range (0, 50):
      time.sleep(0.01)
      helpers.update_position(canvas, 'car1', x=counter, y=0)
      gui.update()
```